# Changing an imported class variable

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, class, variables

I have this problem where I'm trying to change a class variable that has been imported into two separate files.

In `settings.py`.

```
class Settings:
    Flag = True
```

In `slave.py.`

```
from settings import Settings

if(...):
    Settings.Flag = False
    print('Flag is False')
else:
    ...
```

In `main.py`

```
from settings import Settings

While True:
    print('Status of Flag : ' str(Settings.Flag))
```

Even if I change it so Flag is changed to False in Slave.py. It still returns True in main.py.

I thought this might be because I'm importing settings in both Slave.py & main.py. But taking this out just gives me an error.

Answer (score 2):

You should import slave.py in main.py in order to run his code as well as i don't see any reference to the file slave.py

Try this:

```
from settings import Settings
import slave

While True:
    print('Status of Flag : ' str(Settings.Flag))
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you are trying to control the variables in one process from another. I observe that `main.py` makes no reference to the `slave` module, and therefore deduce that you are running `slave.py` separately (*e.g.* you run `main.py` in one window and `slave.py` in another).

Consider the following modules:

settings.py:

```
class Settings:
    Flag = True
```

slave.py:

```
from settings import Settings

def change_value(v):
    Settings.Flag = v
```

main.py:

```
from settings import Settings
from slave import change_value

print('Status of Flag :', str(Settings.Flag))
change_value(False)
print('Status of Flag :', str(Settings.Flag))
change_value(True)
print('Status of Flag :', str(Settings.Flag))
```

Now when you run `main.py` you should see the output

```
('Status of Flag :', 'True')
('Status of Flag :', 'False')
('Status of Flag :', 'True')
```

This works because now all the modules are a part of the same process, and so both `main.py` and `slave.py` are importing the same instance of the `slave` module, and therefore both are referring to the same `Settings` instance.

If you really need to affect the behaviour of one process from another then you must use some specific mechanism for [*inter-process communication*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication), a topic rather too broad for the scope of this answer.

Comment: Thank you for that. However now the Flag status reflects correctly in main.py. But if it is changed in Slave.py. The main.py flag only reflects the status that is set in main.py. I need the status to be the same across my program.

Comment: I'm not sure you have communicated your entire meaning, then. It might be a useful exercise to put the `Settings` object and the `change_value` function into the same module. Then you would observe that the value of the flag could be changed by any module that imported the `settings` module. It's only a short step from there to make `change_value` a method of the `Settings` class.